# What does "なんだもんなあ" mean?

Tags: reading-comprehension, no-da, particle-mono

> 同じ部屋とかもう慣れてるはずなのに"

> 当たり前のようにダブルべっどなんだもんなぁ

In the first line the character is like "We should be already used to sleep in the same room and yet"

By context I can gather the character is embarrassed to sleep in a double bed with their boyfriend. However, I'm stumbled by the actual nuance?

"Like it's natural, we got a double bed?"

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the character is still kind of shocked how nonchalantly there is a double bed. I wouldn’t necessarily say “embarrassed”, it’s more like “feels unreal”.